# bootstrap navbar form under the navbar brand and link

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to make the form for the username,password, and button to be on the same line as the navbar brand and the a tags but for some reason it appears to be under them.

What would be the fix for this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Log Me In! </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navHeaderCollapse">

  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="" value="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <input type="button" id="logIn" value="Login">
  </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The problem in your code is that `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">` should be closed before line you are closing the `<div class="container">` and not after `<ul>` like you are doing. Regards. I add too a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your form inside collapsible div

this is how you can do

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Log Me In! </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">

  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id= "navHeaderCollapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
 
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="" value="" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"  id="logIn" value="Login">
  </form>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and also give `class="form-control"` to your textboxes and `class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"` to get nice well styled button :) expand snippet(full screen) to see changes, i have made your menu collapsible too , it's not working in your given example

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for as well, noted! Love the style tips! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the form within your div with class "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" like this.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    </ul>

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="username" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="" value="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="logIn" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, noted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

take a look.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Log Me In !</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Can you check the result in codepen https://codepen.io/ricopo/pen/ZKXOYQ

Hope I helped you!

Comment: A rookie mistake for me haha, noted! This worked for me thank you!